# Trouble with Android App Uncaught Exceptions in the Log

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

When I launch my app I get the following errors in the log. Can you anyone decipher some of them for me, and give me a potential solution? I would be so grateful if you could as its proving very frustrating and I am new to Android development. I am using Eclipse SDK with an Android AVD at 1.6 SDK level.

Thanks..

> 07-17 11:05:57.046:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226): Uncaught
>   handler: thread main exiting due to
>   uncaught exception   07-17
>   11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 
>   start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.darius.android.distractions/com.darius.android.distractions.Distractions}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.widget.FrameLayout 07-17
>   11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
>   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
>   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
>   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
>   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
>   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method)   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit
>   $MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
>   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
>   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
>   Method)     07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226): Caused by: 
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.widget.FrameLayout     07-17
>   11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   com.darius.android.distractions.Distractions.onCreate(Distractions.java:87)
>   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
>   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
>   07-17 11:05:57.056:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     ... 11 
>   more

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on line 87 of your Distractions class.

The error stack complaining of a ClassCastException which is thrown when a program attempts to cast an object to a type with which it is not compatible.

It looks like you are trying to cast a FrameLayout as something it is not.

Good tip for decoding the error stack, look for the line that says Caused by: This line will give you a reason for the error and the line below will show you where the error is happening and will include a line reference so you can easily find the problem.